# Ignore a null point exception and carry on

Tags: java

i have written some code that takes an ip address inputted from a text file full of addresses and converts these to the physical location

however occasionally the results will give a null pointer exception - kinda to be expected due to the text file being inputted sometimes not being 100% formatted correctly, however when i have over a million addresses the null pointer exception can be a bit annoying stopping my program haha - can i code in such a way which catches the exception and just carries on ?

```
     public convert() {

//            System.out.println("in test");
            Locate obj = new Locate();
            String file = "Bitcoin_IP.txt";

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
//                System.out.println(line);

                    ServerLocation location = obj.getLocation(line);
                    System.out.println(location);

                    try {
                        String filename = "Locations.txt";
                        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true)) {
                            fw.write(location + "\n");
                        }
                    } catch (NullPointerException ioe) {
                        System.err.println("NullPointerException: " + ioe.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Locate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you think it's to be expected? I can't see why you'd get a `NullPointerException` in the code you've shown...

Comment: (Basically, rather than catching `NullPointerException`, you should check whether the value of the relevant variable is `null` and act accordingly.)

Comment: Did u consider move `ServerLocation location = obj.getLocation(line); ` inside the `try` block?

Answer (score 0):

You're already catching `NPE` for some of the code, so if you are still getting those particular exceptions they must be originating here:

```
                ServerLocation location = obj.getLocation(line);
```

So try this:

```
                try {
                    ServerLocation location = obj.getLocation(line);
                    System.out.println(location);

                    String filename = "Locations.txt";
                    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true)) {
                        fw.write(location + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException ioe) {
                    System.err.println("NullPointerException: " + ioe.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: You should never catch nullpointer exceptions. Instead you should check if your object is not null. if (obj != null)

Comment: What if `getLocation(line)` throws a NullPointerException?

Comment: If it's from a library you own, you should check what's causing it there. If it's an external library and you can't do a check beforehand, then it's out of your control and you have a valid reason to catch a NPE